# Windows Login Prompt When Accessing Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, iis

I receive a Windows login prompt when accessing a site on IIS with a host other than localhost.

For example,
    `http://localhost/mysite -- works
    http://ipaddresss/mysite -- login prompt`

If I enable Anonymous Access in the IIS settings for the web application, the prompt goes away and I can access the site fine. I have Windows Authentication enabled as well.

I want to be able to disable Anonymous Access without getting the windows login prompt.

Windows IIS 7.5
Windows Server 2008 R2
ASP.NET 4.5 MVC Web application

This does not seem to be browser related.  I get the same behavior whether it's IE or Firefox.

Comment: You don't want to enable 'Anonymous Access', neither ask for login... Seems a bit contradictory, don't?

Comment: are you familiar with `PrincipalContext` perhaps you can do some Domain Authenticating in the background if I am understanding your issue correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an internet setting, which can be changed in IE or the control panel.

Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet -> Sites - Making your your site/domain is in the list

IE is prompting for windows credentials if it's not in the Intranet Zone or not in the list of intranet sites. Add the site to your intranet zones list for automatic login.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to resolve the problem.

In IE, I added the IP address to the local intranet sites in the Security tab.

Apparently Windows Integrated Security is only guaranteed in IE.

I used this Knowledge Base Article as a reference. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063