# Windows Authentication prompt appears if you access via domain name

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, networkcredentials

I have a web application hosted in IIS and configured with Windows Authentication. It is supposed to be SSO (Single sign-on) and work without prompting users for their credentials. It works in this way if I access it via server name or cname. Example:

```
https://serverName/applicationName
https://cname/applicationName
```

However, it asks for user credentials if I access the application via full domain name such as:

```
https://serverName.domain.com/applicationName
https://cname.domain.com/applicationName
```

Any ideas what the issue would be?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Login Prompt When Accessing Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431535/windows-login-prompt-when-accessing-site)