# Website asking for windows credentials each time

Tags: iis-10, windows-server-2019

I have a website published in IIS 10(windows server 2019), in which I have enabled the Windows authentication and disabled the Anonymous authentication.(Then only I am getting windows credential in my application, otherwise getting the IUSR in all machines). Now when I opened the application in IE (even in chrome), it is asking for the windows credentials every time. IS there anyway to disable the windows credentials and still get the credentials in the application.? The same application working fine in IIS 7(Windows server 2008 R2)

I have tried all the settings in IIS authentication but nothing is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Login Prompt When Accessing Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431535/windows-login-prompt-when-accessing-site)

Answer (score 1):

According to your descritpion, I suggest you could try to modify IE setting to access your web application.

The IE has the security setting which will send the current login in windows user name and password automatically.

More details about how to modify the IE setting, you could refer to below steps.

1.Open the IE and find the internet options.

[image]

2.Modify the user authentication

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this and it is working great. But I cannot do this in every users machine. So I am looking for any solution that I can do it in the server

Comment: "But I cannot do this in every users machine" is incorrect. Talk to your domain administrators and they can push the policies down to all machines.

Comment: Thank you . I will check with them